# Howto Reference a class in typeid()

Tags: c++

i try to map the type of a class to an enumeration. I know that one shouldn't try this in general (bad design), but in my case I want to use the enum as parameter for a CUDA kernel. An I cannot pass Host objects to the Device. Enough on the background of my problem.

I try to check whether a given object is an instance of a specific class by doing:

```
if(typeid(object) == typeid(NameSpaceName::ClassName)){...
```

I get the following compiler error on this:

```
error: ‘ClassName’ is not a member of ‘NameSpaceName’
```

`ClassName` is declared by

```
namespace NameSpaceName{
   class ClassName{};
}
```

For the sake of completeness, `ClassName` is derived from an abstract Class. I think this has nothing to do with the resolution of the reference to `ClassName`?

Any ideas what my problem is?

Comment: Are you sure, that compiler should see definition of `NameSpaceName::ClassName` in `if(typeid(object) == typeid(NameSpaceName::ClassName))`?

Comment: Try `::NameSpaceName::ClassName` maybe... also, could you please choose less confusing identifiers for the example? Things like `class _class { int int_ } class_;` are just very tiresome to parse. Compare this with `class Foo { int n; } x;`.

Comment: You do include whatever header file `NameSpaceName::ClassName` is defined in?

Comment: wow, I should hide right now, just didn't include as @JoachimPileborg suspected...